# Xamarin forms : Prism framework FileNotFoundException - Prism.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, xamarin-studio

I am trying to develop xamarin forms with PRISM framework. I added 
prism.core, prism.forms, prism.unity.forms in all projects. 
When I run it I am getting the following error in iOS Project

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Prism.Forms' or one of its dependencies.
```

When i download n run sample xamarin forms with prism framework, i am able to. Can anyone guide me or help me resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the solution?

Comment: I did. still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that the reference isn't added.  I would double check.  The easiest way to get started is to use the Prism Template Pack

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e7b6bde2-ba59-43dd-9d14-58409940ffa0

Then use the File -> New -> Prism Unity App project template.  It will create the entire project ready to go for you.

Comment: Brian, I did as you asked. Its taking me 20 minutes and still running to add the packages for Prism Unity App. Is it normal ?

Comment: Never mind, I stopped it after few minutes and manually added prism components in all files and its working now. 
Thank you Brian.